How to Set the Partition Scheme to "Huge APP (3MB No OTA/1 MB SPIFFS)" in PlatformIO for ESP32 WROOM?
I'm working on a project using the ESP32 WROOM module and PlatformIO. I need to set the partition scheme to "Huge APP (3MB No OTA/1 MB SPIFFS)" to accommodate my application requirements.
Could someone guide me on how to configure this partition scheme in PlatformIO?
Additional Details:
Development Board: ESP32 WROOM
Development Environment: PlatformIO
I added the board_build.partitions directive in my platformio.ini file, hoping to set the partition scheme.


Open your platformio.ini file
add board_build.partitions = huge_app.csv
clean, build and you are done.

Referance link : here
If you still have difficulties, please follow below steps

Set the Partition Scheme:

Create a partitions folder in the root of your project if it doesn't exist.
Create a huge_app.csv file inside this folder with the following content:

# Name,   Type, SubType, Offset,  Size, Flags
nvs,      data, nvs,     0x9000,  0x5000,
otadata,  data, ota,     0xe000,  0x2000,
app0,     app,  ota_0,   0x10000, 0x300000,
spiffs,   data, spiffs,  0x310000,0xF0000,


Save and Build: Save the changes and build your project.



